# React: .map method statement returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, undefined, array.prototype.map

I have the following function;

```
    const ListallSpaces = newSubject.map(mySpaces => {
         const urlToBeSplit = mySpaces.s
         const onlySpaceNames = urlToBeSplit.split('/')[5]
         const subject = []
           return (
             subject.push({subject: [onlySpaceNames]}),
             console.log("subject", subject)
           )
        }) 
   console.log(ListallSpaces)
```

if i console.log(subject) it returns an array containing a certain space, which is the value i need. However, if i console.log the ListallSpaces it returns undefined. is there a reason why?

Comment: you need to return something from the map function. currently you're returning array.push and console.log, both return undefined

Comment: See the "comma operator" for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return something.

The below example will return an array with one element. That element will be an object.

```
const ListallSpaces = newSubject.map(mySpaces => {
     const urlToBeSplit = mySpaces.s
     const onlySpaceNames = urlToBeSplit.split('/')[5]
     const subject = [{subject: [onlySpaceNames]}]
     return subject
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: This is true, but without explaining the comma operator it's not useful to OP

Answer (score 0):

it is giving undefined as in your return statement your push command gives 1 and console.log gives you undefined.
To make this work you have to return the subject.
just try this.
`subject.push({ subject: [onlySpaceNames] }); return subject;`